# C program malloc with array of strings

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

At the beginning of a program I need to dynamically allocate memory for an unknown number of strings with unknown number of size to later manipulate with. To get the number of strings from a user I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int number = atoi(argv[1]);
```

So far so good. "number" now holds holds the number that the user inputted on the command line for executing the code. Now here comes the part I don't quite understand. I now need to dynamically store the lengths of the strings as well as the contents of the strings. For example, I want the program to function like this:

```
Enter the length of string 1: 5
Please enter string 1: hello
Enter the length of string 2: ...
```

For this I recognize that I will have to create an array of strings. However, I can't quite understand the concept of pointers to pointers and what not. What I would like is perhaps a simplification of how this gets accomplished?

Comment: What do you exactly need in your program?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava I would like these strings to later compare lengths, concatenate them, copy them, etc. but I'm familiar with those things. I just don't know how to dynamically allocate them if there are an unknown number with unknown lengths.

Comment: `Enter the length of string 1: 5` then `Please enter string 1: hello` **Be Careful**, while you can store 5 characters `'h''e''l''l''o'`, in an *array [5] char*, it will NOT be a *string* of characters. (there is no *nul-terminating* character at the end -- which would require 6-characters of storage) Any attempt to use the array containing `"hello"` as a *string* will result in *Undefined Behavior* as the string-function madly searches all through your stack looking for a *nul-character*...

Comment: Also, don't use `atoi(argv[1])` -- it provides *Zero* error checking capabilities (what if `argv[1] = "duck"`?. Instead use `strtol` which provides solid error handling capabilities.

Comment: the first thing the program should be doing is testing `argc` to assure that the user actually entered a parameter.  If no parameter entered, the output a `USAGE` statement (fprintf( stderr, (USAGE: %s [numberOfStrings]\n", argv[0] );` then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )`  where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in `stdlib.h`

Comment: The program should catch the error when the first Inputs from the user are: `Enter the length of string 1: 5
Please enter string 1: hello`  Because `hello`, as a string, requires room for the trailing NUL char, so the length should be 6.  However, rather than requiring the user to know that detail, just input into a large buffer ( or use the posix function: `getline()` ) then determine the length of the data (size_t length = strlen(buffer) +1; )  Then allocate the needed area, then copy (`strcpy()` ) the data from the input buffer to the allocated memory  Then the user does not need the lengt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know from the start you will have `number` strings to store so you will need an array of size `number` to store a pointer to each string.

You can use `malloc` to dynamically allocate enough memory for `number` char pointers:

```
char** strings = malloc(number * sizeof(char*));
```

Now you can loop `number` times and allocate each string dynamically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
   // Get length of string
   printf("Enter the length of string %d: ", i);
   int length = 0;
   scanf("%d", &length);

   // Clear stdin for next input
   int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();

   // Allocate "length" characters and read in string
   printf("Please enter string %d: ", i);
   strings[i] = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
   fgets(strings[i], length, stdin);
}
```

Comment: I can follow most of this. Just to clarify: a char** would be a pointer to a pointer to char? And as for fgets I am unfamiliar with that function but I can research that. Thank you.

Comment: You are right about `char**`, it is a pointer to a character pointer. In this case, if `char*` is a string, `char**` is essentially a dynamically allocated array if strings.

Comment: And you can read about [`fgets` here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/)

Comment: Haha a pointer to a pointer bends my brain a little bit, but thank you for the answer and for where I can learn about new functions.

Comment: the program asks for the length of string just fine, but loops over and doesn't take input for the content of the string?

Comment: You should add `++length;` just after the scan to reserve space for the string termination

Comment: @ClockwerkSC The string is "empty" (or rather just a newline) because `scanf("%d", &length);` has left a newline in the stream. So the `fgets` just reads that newline. The above code doesn't handle this correctly.

Comment: Unless you have redirected a file holding 10 numbers as input `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` will invoke *Undefined Behavior* as `stdin` is not seekable unless the input is provided by file-redirection. (e.g. a seekable file) To clear `stdin` to end of line, just use `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();`

Comment: Good answer `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to save **both** the length and the string, I'll suggest that you put them together in a struct. Like

```
struct string
{
    int length;
    char* str;
};
```

Now you can dynamically create an array of this struct and dynamically assign memory for the individual strings.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct string
{
    int length;
    char* str;
};

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char tmp[128];
    int number = 3;
    struct string* strings = malloc(number * sizeof *strings);

    // read the input
    for (i=0; i<number; ++i)
    {
        printf("length?\n");
        if (fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            printf("error 1");
            exit(1);
        }
        int length;
        if (sscanf(tmp, "%d", &length) != 1)
        {
            printf("error 2");
            exit(1);
        }
        strings[i].length = length;
        strings[i].str = calloc(length + 2, 1);
        printf("string?\n");
        if (fgets(strings[i].str, length + 2, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            printf("error 3");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (strings[i].str[length] != '\n')
        {
            printf("error 4");
            exit(1);
        }
        strings[i].str[length] = '\0';
    }

    // print the strings
    for (i=0; i<number; ++i)
    {
      printf("len=%d str=%s\n", strings[i].length, strings[i].str);
    }

    // Clean up, i.e. free the memory allocated
    for (i=0; i<number; ++i)
    {
        free(strings[i].str);
    }
    free(strings);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: You should also check that all `malloc`/`calloc` are succesful, i.e. doesn't return NULL. For clarity I skipped that.

Comment: By reading the exact number of characters exactly with `fgets(strings[i].str, length + 1, stdin)` `fgets` will use the `+1` as storage for the *nul-character* and you will leave each `'\n'` (generated by the user pressing *[Enter]*) unread in `stdin`, this must be removed before your next call to `fgets` to avoid reading the unread `'\n'` as your next input.